# What's the relationship between a diplomatic mission and a delegation?

Tags: terminology, international-relations

Sometimes I see this terminology used interchangeably, and I've been reading Wikipedia definitions, but it's just not clear what the difference between "delegation" and "mission" is.

For instance, there is: **The Delegation of the European Union to the United States**

And the counterpart seems to be:  **The United States Mission to the European Union**

Both of these are headed by an Ambassador.  (David O’Sullivan and Luzzatto Gardner respectively)

So is a delegation and a mission the same thing?  Can a mission have multiple delegations?  Can a delegation have multiple missions?  My question is general and not necessarily confined to the the specific example I mentioned.

Comment: I think it's in fact somewhat specific to your example: The EU is not a country and its diplomatic missions have to co-exist with that of its member states. And the word “delegation” was already in use when their role was much more modest than it is under the Lisbon treaty.